# Comparing value from a nested dictionaries and list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, comparison, nested-lists

I want to compare values from two variables (dictionary and list). Dictionary has a nested construct, so I have to loop over the all items. 
I discovered simple solution, but I am pretty sure that I can do this in a better way (using python). 
In a brief I want to find items from `user_from_database` which are not existing in a `user_from_client` variable.

**My solution:**

```
#variable containing users from client side
users_from_client = {
  "0": {
    "COL1": "whatever",
    "COL2": "val1",
    "COL3": "whatever",
  },
  "1": {
    "COL1": "whatever",
    "COL2": "val2",
    "COL3": "whatever",
  },
  "3": {
    "COL1": "whatever",
    "COL2": "val3",
    "COL3": "whatever",
  }    
} 

#variable containing users from the database
users_from_database = [
  ["val1"],
  ["val2"],
  ["val5"],
  ["val7"]
]

#This function is used to find element from the nested dictionaries(d)
def _check(element, d, pattern = 'COL2'):
  exist = False
  for k, user in d.iteritems():
    for key, item in user.iteritems():
      if key == pattern and item == element:
        exist = True
  return exist

#Finding which users should be removed from the database  
to_remove = []
for user in users_from_db:
  if not _check(user[0], users_from_agent):
    if user[0] not in to_remove:
      to_remove.append(user[0])

#to_remove list contains: [val5, val7"]
```

What is the better way to give the same result using python approach ? 
Probably I don't have to add that I'm a newbie with python (I assume that you are able to see that watching the code above).

Comment: Why are you enclosing each "val" in it's own list in `users_from_database`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an [error-safe dictionary lookup](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```
def _check(element, d, pattern = 'COL2'):
    for user in d.itervalues():
        if user.get(pattern) == element:
            return True
    return False
```

Or as a one liner:

```
def _check(element, d, pattern = 'COL2'):
    return any(user.get(pattern) == element for user in d.itervalues())
```

Or trying to do the entire job as a one-liner:

```
#Finding which users should be removed from the database  
to_remove = set(
    name
    for name in users_from_database.itervalues()
    if not any(user.get('COL2') == name for (user,) in users_from_client)
)

assert to_remove == {"val5", "val7"}
```

`set`s can make it ever more concise (and efficient):

```
to_remove = set(
    user for (user,) in users_from_database
) - set(
    user.get('COL2') for user in users_from_client
)
```

---

Your data structures are a bit wierd. Consider using:

```
users_from_client = [
  {
    "COL1": "whatever",
    "COL2": "val1",
    "COL3": "whatever",
  }, {
    "COL1": "whatever",
    "COL2": "val2",
    "COL3": "whatever",
  }, {
    "COL1": "whatever",
    "COL2": "val3",
    "COL3": "whatever",   
  }
] 

#variable containing users from the database
users_from_database = set(
  "val1",
  "val2",
  "val5",
  "val7"
)
```

Which reduces your code to:

```
to_remove = users_from_database - set(
    user.get('COL2') for user in users_from_client
)
```

Comment: Note that this requires you to make sure that `None` is not a valid dictionary value.

Comment: To be honest, it might make more sense to just let the `KeyError` be thrown. As a hack, you could use `user.get('COL2', float('nan'))`

Comment: I know that it doesn't look good, but unfortunately I get this structure from one function. Of course I can add one more iteration for removing unnecessary list, but I don't see any sense of that approach (one more iteration...)

Comment: @user1119698: Can you rewrite that function? Also, iterations don't have to happen sequentially - they can happen in parallel

Comment: @user1119698: I've updated my one-liners to work with the original data structure

Comment: Results come from the database function - fetchAll. I can parse my results in a separate function and return desired results. One more step in the flow :)

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know of any super elegant way to do this, but there are some minor improvements you can make to your code.

First off, you aren't using `k`, so you might as well iterate over just the values. Second, you don't need to keep track of `exists`, you can just return immediately when you find a match. Lastly, if you're checking for a key,value pair, you can just test if the tuple is contained in items.

```
def _check(element, d, pattern = 'COL2'):
  for user in d.itervalues():
    if (pattern, element) in user.items():
      return True
  return False
```

Comment: Thx, your code looks much better than mine. Comparision of tuples is great!

Answer (score 0):

You can create inverted dict for fast lookup and place it in cache for example..

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> 
>>> users_inverted = defaultdict(list)
>>> for pk, user in users_from_client.iteritems():
...  for key in user.iteritems():
...   users_inverted[key].append(int(pk))
... 
>>> users_inverted
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {('COL3', 'whatever'): [1, 0, 3], ('COL2', 'val1'): [0], ('COL1', 'whatever'): [1, 0, 3], ('COL2', 'val2'): [1], ('COL2', 'val3'): [3]})
```

and then lookup for users will be very fast:

```
>>> def _check(element, pattern = 'COL2'):
...  return bool(users_inverted[(pattern, element)])
>>> 
>>> _check('whatever', 'COL3')
True
>>> _check('whatever', 'COL333')
False
```

and as a plus besides speed you get a list of users for each attributes pair